# react native : there is way to do an acordion table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to make an accordion display that when click then it will displays the table as in my example in accordion form?

[this is the snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/@roei133/table-example)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';

export default class ExampleOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['this is my drop table'],
      tableData: [
        ['1', '2'],
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['1', '2'],
        ['a', 'b']
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6 }
});
```

in this example i show an accordion that it should open up and display my table as i show above. 
[and this is my accordion that i want to use for show my table](https://snack.expo.io/@roei133/hello-world?platform=android&name=Hello%20World&dependencies=react-navigation%40%5E4.0.10%2Creact-navigation-tabs%40%5E2.5.6%2Creact-navigation-stack%40%5E1.10.3%2Creact-navigation-drawer%40%5E2.3.3&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F4.x%2Fhello-react-navigation.js)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { List, Checkbox } from 'react-native-paper';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    expanded: true
  }

  _handlePress = () =>
    this.setState({
      expanded: !this.state.expanded
    });

  render() {
    return (
      <List.Section style={{ marginTop:50}}>
        <List.Accordion
          title="drop list table" style={{backgroundColor:'pink'}}
          left={props => <List.Icon {...props} />}
        >
          <List.Item title="table item1" />
          <List.Item title="table item2" />
          <List.Item title="table item3" />
          <List.Item title="table item4" />
        </List.Accordion>
      </List.Section>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below example which I created using **react-native-collapsible/Accordion**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

export default class ExampleOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeSections: [],
      section: [
        {
          tableHead: ['this is my drop table'],
          tableData: [['1', '2'], ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['a', 'b']],
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  renderHeader = section => {
    console.log('state', section);
    let index = this.state.activeSections[0];
    let currentObj = this.state.section[index];
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text>{section.tableHead}</Text>

        <Image
          style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
          source={
            currentObj == section
              ? {
                  uri:
                    'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-down-512.png',
                }
              : {
                  uri:
                    'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-512.png',
                }
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  renderContent = section => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
          <Rows data={section.tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  };

  updateSections = activeSections => {
    this.setState({ activeSections });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Accordion
        sections={this.state.section}
        activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
        renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
        renderContent={this.renderContent}
        onChange={this.updateSections}
        duration={500}
        underlayColor="#fff"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: { padding: 6 },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    marginTop: 5,
    width: '92%',
    borderTopColor: '#E9E9E9',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 6,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '92%',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#c8e1ff',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

Change this according to your requirement.

Comment: i have checked and its working fine. you should copy full code. check again.

Comment: 1. something not good in your example because when i press on the button so the button background become black in the sides ..i dont understand why its like that.
2 . it should have an icon of down arrow on the button .

Comment: for background color you need to add **underlayColor**  i have edited my answer. however  if you need to add a **icon** using this library you have to customize ** renderHeader** if i could, i will let you know

Comment: what i need to install in console ? what npm for accordion ?

Comment: if i install this : npm install react-native-collapsible/Accordion --save , so it give an error: Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: [check this link](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible)

Comment: i have added  arrow icons and updated above answer. i hope this is what you want. let me know if it works